# Use array for filtering Prisma nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

having an array with unique names, how can i update the elemets of those names using prisma(in nextjs).
I mean something Like:

```
const arr=['Joe', 'Mark'];
const update=await prisma.user.updateMany({
    where: {
        name: //What should i put to update both Joe and Mark?
    },
    data: {
        notifications: {push: "Hello"}
    }
});
```

I'm using PSQL and i don't know if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const arr=['Joe', 'Mark'];

const update=await prisma.user.updateMany({
    where: {
        name: {in: arr}
    },
    data: {
        notifications: {push: "Hello"}
    }
});
```

"in" will check if name matches anything in that array.
Here is the list of other filters: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#filter-conditions-and-operators

Comment: Thanks, that help and also thank for the documentation